# Run molecule bash command in flask project

Tags: python, bash, flask, molecule

I have following code structure

1. flask project

   - |->app1->here I'm writing following code
   - |->app2
2. ansible project

   - |->roles->myrole->molecule
   - |-> Playbooks

I want to check ansible roles linting so I'm using python molecule package for this

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'cd ~/ansible/roles/myrole && molecule lint'
out = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=False)
```

Every time it is giving me

> Exception [Error 2] No such file for directory

Comment: You need `shell=True` to parse a single string (which contains a shell command list, not just a single executable and its arguments).

Comment: That also I tried in that case it is giving me molecule command not found

Comment: Where is `molecule` installed? That directory does not appear to have been added to your `PATH`. (To be clear, it's still a problem to be fixed, but changing to `shell=True` is progress; before, it was treating the entire value of `cmd` as the name of a command to execute.)

Comment: It's in myrole folder

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that in the top half of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a single shell command in a string, stick with pure Python as much as possible.

```
import os
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path


os.chdir(Path.home() / "ansible/roles/myrole")
out = subprocess.run(["./molecule", "lint"])
```

or just

```
out = subprocess.run(["./molecule", "lint"], cwd=Path.home() / "ansible/roles/myrole")
```

Comment: The local directory is not on your `PATH`; you need to provide a full (whether relative or absolute) path to the executable.

Comment: Now after changes molecule command asking me permission but if I run same command using command line it is not asking me permission

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question. `molecule` is running.